# Schema.org in a directory website

Tags: seo, local-seo, schema.org

Is it possible to introduce Schema.org markup (using JSON-LD) in a directory website?

My website shows restaurants from a region, but the restaurants are not mine.

I'm thinking to introduce address, opening time, ….

Comment: Yes. Check this out: https://schema.org/Restaurant

Comment: but, if it's not the official website, could google take me as spam?

Comment: No. Directories for restaurants, hotels, beaches, bars, and what not exist all over the web. The question becomes, how do you separate yourself from the rest? Are you adding value? Google, for example, wants you to be better for users separating yourself from your competition by serving people better. It only has to be one simple thing you do better, however, if you can find more than one, the better for you.

Comment: Do you mean with the vocabulary Schema.org? Because JSON-LD is just a format/syntax that can be used with any kind of vocabulary.

Comment: yes, I mean Schema.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course.

For marking up entities (like restaurants, people, things, ideas, documents, etc.) with the vocabulary Schema.org, it’s irrelevant if these entities belong to you in any kind of way.

I could, for example, state data about you on my site:

```html
<div typeof="schema:Person">
  <a property="schema:sameAs" href="http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/53655/saimonx">
    <span property="schema:name">saimonx</span>
  </a> 
  has won the 
  <span property="schema:award">foobar award</span>.
</div>
```

So it’s possible, and useful, to use the [`Restaurant` type](http://schema.org/Restaurant) for each restaurant in your directory.

With the property [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) you could link to the restaurant’s official website (or its Wikipedia article etc.).