# Does it make sense to put Google Video Snippet of a non hosted video?

Tags: rich-snippets, video, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a website with a bunch of videos from an API which sends me the URL of the video, so not the `<embed>` nor the `<iframe>`. What I do is to play them with the HTML5 `video` element.

Would it be a good idea (SEO speaking) to create those [snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/videos#video_markup_properties)? As videos are not mine and may be in other websites as well, I don't know if is allowed or even a good idea to put them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s a good idea.

Structured data is not only useful for content you authored. It allows you to [say anything about anything](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82706/17633) (see [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) and [Linked Data](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData)).

You provide this video for your human visitors, possibly showing its title and other metadata. Why not also provide this data in a way that machines can easier understand?
Or in other words: *Any* entity (an object, an organization, a person, a concept, a work, an idea, etc.) you have content about on your page is a possible candidate for providing structured data about it.

---

FWIW, here’s a related Google Webmasters video about this:

[Should I add schema.org markup on my videos even if they're on YouTube?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePG5YYHU5Jo)

> Rich snippets are automatically added to SERPs for video results from YouTube. Is it recommended to add schema video markup onsite in order to get your page w/embedded video to rank in SERPs in addition to the YouTube result, or is this redundant?

tl;dw: *Yes, please get them to add the markup.*