# Can I use Accommodation or Hotel Schema markup if customers can't book it

Tags: schema.org

We sell ferry travel, and want to capture customers browsing holidays to the destinations in order to raise awareness of going by ferry.

On this page we mention the different types of holiday accomm you could book on the islands and give 3 examples of each. 3 hotels, 3 resorts/holiday parks & 3 self catering apartments.

Can we use the accommodation markup schema, or as we don't mention price and you can't book would this be pointless?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific benefit you are looking for in implementing this structured data? Are you attempting to get rich snippets for the hotel details in Google SERPs?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate (at least the answer would be almost the same): [Schema.org in a directory website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82647/17633)

Comment: Yes, our competitor has a rich snippet when users search for 'Jersey Holidays' it's pulls up a bulleted list of hotels, this is the page they marked up https://www.channelislandsdirect.co.uk/the_islands/jersey you can enquire about an offer but not actually book on this site